# How to write spark output on disk while using standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark on my local machine. It was installed as a standalone mode. I have not installed Hadoop or other Resource Managers. I am conducting my analysis in python language and is using Windows OS. Everything goes fine with processing the data, but at last when I try to write the output in disk I always encounter a problem: Py4JJava error. My lines of codes are as follows and the specific error message is also posted here. Please help.
#creating SparkSession
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

## load data

df = spark.read.text(r"D:\my_project\word_count_with_Apache_Spark\test text file.txt")
df.show()

## word count

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

## Split lines into words

words = df.select(F.explode(F.split(df.value, " ")).alias("word"))

## Clean the words (optional): Remove punctuation and convert to lowercase

cleaned_words = words.withColumn("word", F.lower(F.regexp_replace("word", "[^a-zA-Z]", "")))

## Filter out empty strings

cleaned_words = cleaned_words.filter(cleaned_words.word != '')

## Count the words

word_counts = cleaned_words.groupBy("word").count().orderBy("count", ascending=False)

## Show the top 20 words by count

word_counts.show(20, truncate=False)

## write to disk

word_counts.write.format("csv").save("/temp/spark_output/datacsv")

I faced this problem 5 days ago and I tried various ways. Each time I got Py4JJavaError. I googled the problem, used chatgpt or any other means possible to solve this problem. I reviewed the configurations for spark and pyspark and it seems ok. What I haven't tried till now is installing Hadoop only. I created a fake Hadoop directory also to create a dummy environment variable, but it didn't work. I couldn't even convert my dataframe into Pandas dataframe. Registering output in temp table seems ok, but the SQL queries ran on it displays errors again.

Edit: But I think it is not from path issues. I tried frontslashes, backslashes, double slashes, or even used 'r'. But each time it shows error relating to Hadoop. The installation of my Spark seems ok-- a pre-built version for Hadoop, files extraction was ok. I cannot say it that it's 100% not corrupted, but to my best knowledge it's fine. When it displayed errors relating to Hadoop regarding winutils.exe file, I downloaded it to newly created Hadoop directory (fake), set HADOOP_HOME variable and the path. But the problem persisted each time. I have been dealing with it for some days. I am sure it is not memory issue. I changed the way I create SparkSession to explicitly denote memory config, and this test file file I used here is very tiny for Spark.

Comment: The error is probably from the fact that you are using Windows OS, but the path syntax looks like UNIX. Try changing it to just `word_counts.write.format("csv").save("test.csv")`, it should save it to the folder where you are executing the Spark script.

Comment: What has that got to do with stand alone?

Comment: But unfortunately it is not due to the path issues. Whether I use black slashes, front slashes or double slashes to denote the path, it just create a an empty folder with no saved data. This empty folder is created to any directory for the path I provide. And each time it displays the same error relating to hadoop.

Comment: Thank you community. With the installation of windows subsystem for Linux, the problem is solved. It was may be due to the compatibility issues.